# Using aspell with pipes from the command line by specifying dictionary

Tags: linux, command-line, aspell, spelling

I have the following problem. I have a list of words in a file "a.dict". Amongst them are specific brand names (not just words from a dictionary). For example something like

```
kellogs
milk
peanut
cheese
starbucks
```

This is my dictionary I want to check against "a.dict". Additionally, I have another file with words entered by humans which have spell errors in them, something like

```
kelohs
milk
walmart
cheeeze
```

I would like to use GNU's aspell to do the following.
1) Detect if there is an exact match with the words in the dictionary
2) If possible output the most likely corrected word with some score so that I can choose whether to accept the correction at a certain level.

Is there a way to do this easily on ubuntu using aspell?

Thanks much in advance